# IE 11 ng2 File upload issue in angular 6

Tags: angular6, ng2-file-upload

I have written code for file upload using ng2file upload in angular6. Able to upload multiple files successfully in firefox, chrome and edge but not working for IE11. onSelectedFile() event is triggering twice in Ie11.

I have tried below code:

```
  <input type='file' [uploader]='uploader' multiple (onSelectedFile)='onSelectedFile' ng2fileupload />
```

Any suggestion please.

Comment: If you have already written some code, where's that code? Additionally, what have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: Same. Has anyone found a solution yet?